# Differentiate of the form $y=AB^x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Two points $P(2,5)$ and $Q(4,6)$ lies on a curve $y=AB^x$.

Calculate the rate of change at point P.

Using these two points we can determine the curve equation:

$5=AB^2$ and $6=AB^4$

$\frac{AB^2}{AB^4}=\frac{5}{6}$

$B=\sqrt{\frac{6}{5}}$

$A=5\times \frac{5}{6}=\frac{1}{6}$

$y=\frac{1}{6}\left(\sqrt{\frac{6}{5}}\right)^x$

To find the rate of change; $\frac{dy}{dx}$

This is the part I can't do.

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{6}\left(\sqrt{\frac{6}{5}}\right)^x=?$

Comment: by the way, $A = \frac{25}{6}$; just a small arithmetic error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $y = a^x$. I assume you know that exponential and logarithms are inverses, which means if $\xi > 0$ then $\xi = e^{\ln(\xi)}$. Now, we have
\begin{align}
y &= a^x \\
&= e^{\ln(a^x)} \\
&= e^{x \ln(a)},
\end{align}
the last line is a property of logarithms. Now, remember that $\ln(a)$ is just a constant, so applying the chain rule tells us
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{dx} &= \ln(a) \cdot e^{x \ln(a)} \\
&= \ln(a) \cdot a^x
\end{align}

(Notice how this is almost like $\dfrac{d}{dx}(e^x) = e^x$, except for the constant $\ln(a)$)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:$$y = AB^x$$

$$\implies\frac{dy}{dx} = AB^x\ln(B)$$

[since, $\frac{d}{dx}a^x = a^x\ln(a)$]

Answer (score 0):

The full explanation of the derivative of $y = a^x$ is $\frac{dy}{dx} = \ln(a)\cdot a^x\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}(x) = \ln(a)\cdot a^x \cdot 1 = \ln(a)\cdot a^x$.

Hence the derivative of $y = a^{x^2}$ is $\frac{dy}{dx} = \ln(a)\cdot a^{x^2}\cdot 2x$

The derivative of $y = AB^x$ is $\frac{dy}{dx} = \ln(B)\cdot AB^x\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}(x) = \ln(B)\cdot AB^x \cdot 1 = \ln(B)\cdot AB^x$.

The derivative of $y = e^x$ is therefore $\frac{dy}{dx} = \ln(e)\cdot e^x\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}(x) = 1\cdot e^x\cdot 1 = e^x$